# JSF Теряется ViewState

Tags: java, ajax, jsf

Есть форма регистрации и модальное окно в котором пользователь вводит капчу,всё это в одной HTML форме.Проблема в том что после обновления страницы кнопка в окне срабатывает только со второго раза

Пробовал присваивать id форме и рендерить её,как здесь http://balusc.omnifaces.org/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html#AjaxRenderingOfContentWhichContainsAnotherForm ,не работает

```html
<h:form>
    <h:inputText value="#{Controller.email}" />
 <h:inputText value="#{Controller.password}" />
 <ui:fragment rendered="#{!(Controller.needValidateCaptcha) }">
  <a4j:commandButton action="#{Controller.doRegistration}" value="Зарегистрироваться">    
        </a4j:commandButton> 
     </ui:fragment>
     <ui:fragment rendered="#{(registrationController.needValidateCaptcha) }">
  <button type="button"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Captcha" action="$('#Captcha').modal('show');">Зарегистрироваться</button>
    </ui:fragment>

                 <!-- Попап -->
 <div class="modal" id="Captcha">
  <a4j:outputPanel id="Panel">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
                    <h:inputText id="regcap" value="#{Controller.captcha}"/>
     <ui:fragment rendered="#{Controller.captchaError}">
      <h:outputText value="#{registrationController.captchaErrorMsg}" />
     </ui:fragment>
    </div>
   </div>
  </a4j:outputPanel>
        <a4j:commandButton action="#{Controller.doRegistration}" value="Ok" render="registrationPanel">
        </a4j:commandButton>                   
 </div>      
</h:form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте обновлять родительский элемент для формы. То что вы описываете достаточно распространненая проблемма и [Balus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/157882/balusc) написал сотню ответов на эту тему, например [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10094615/a4jcommandbutton-action-is-only-invoked-on-second-click)

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь публиковать развернутые ответы содержащие конкретный пример минимального решения, дополняя их ссылкой на источник. Ответы–ссылки (как и комментарии) не добавляют знаний в Рунет.